# How to download a .exe automatically (without user interaction) from a web page?

Tags: security

That is when someone opens this web page, the .exe automatically gets downloaded in his system without any user's interaction.

Comment: Great idea! And run it behind the user's back later.

Comment: Wow! What a broad question... If you really wanted to learn this, you'd have already learnt that different browsers incorporate different algorithms. As a result, different browsers often suffer different vulnerabilities at different times. You'd want to mention a target browser, hintedy hint.

Comment: I have heard that some older versions of Internet explorer 5.5 or 6 are vulnerable to attacks. So there is any possibility that i can do this??

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is considered opening a hole for viruses. Most browsers will warn the users that they are about to download an executable and there isn't a way to work around it.

Comment: I want to do this task for my project. I have heard that some older versions of Internet explorer 5.5 or 6 are vulnerable to attacks. So there is any possibility that i can do this??

Comment: If you are running a linux system you could use wget: http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Comment: Thank you. But i have to do this on a windows system.

Comment: This may work then http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
I am not sure though because I haven't used it.